How to disable row click for one column in material react table?
I have enabled row click functionality in a Material React Table to redirect users to a details page. I also want to implement a switch component to enable or disable the user. However, when I click the switch, the row click event is also triggered. How can I prevent this from happening?
const columns = [
columnHelper.accessor('status', {
header: 'Status',
size: 50,
Cell: ({ cell }) => {
    const isActive = cell.getValue()
      const checked = isActive === 'ACTIVE'
      return (
        <Tooltip
          title={isActive === 'ACTIVE' ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}
          placement="left-end"
          arrow
          TransitionComponent={Zoom}
        >
          <Switch
            checked={checked}
            onChange={handleStatusChange}
            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
          />
        </Tooltip>
      )
    },
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor('name', {
    header: 'Name',
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor('code', {
    header: 'Code',
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor('description', {
    header: 'Description',
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor('conflictResolution.priority', {
    header: 'Priority',
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor('createdBy', {
    header: 'Created By',
  }),
]
const table = useMaterialReactTable({
    ...defaultMRTOptions,
    columns,
    data: offers || [],
    onPaginationChange: setPagination,
    state: { pagination, isLoading },
    rowCount: totalRecords,
    muiTableBodyRowProps: ({ row }) => ({
      onClick: () => {
        navigate(`/view/${row.id}`)
      },
      sx: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
      },
    }),
  })


Try adding a stopPropagation on the change event
onChange={(event) => {
  event.stopPropagation(); 
  handleStatusChange(event);
}}

